# ZF2. Как настроить View в ViewHelper при использовании приложения через console?

Tags: консоль, zend-framework-2

Есть задача отправлять email через console. Часть содержимого письма — статистика — формируется через ViewHelper «accountsStat». Сам ViewHelper «accountsStat» также использует другие ViewHelper'ы (например «decodeUrl»).

Как я понял, проблема в том, что при запуске приложения через console, ZF2 не инициализирует View, как это он делает при запуске через http.

Поэтому внутри ViewHelper «accountsStat» пустой $this->getView().

Конечно, при работе с console можно иницилизировать View для каждого ViewHelper'а.

Но как я уже писал, в самом accountsStat.phtml используются другие ViewHelper'ы, которые получается также нужно цеплять к View самостоятельно...

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли решить эту проблему комплексно: т.е. настроить на основе «view_manager» файла «module.config.php» View (+ с учётом \Application\Module->getViewHelperConfig()) для всех ViewHelper'ов, так, как это бы было для http?

Comment: Вы из консоли хотите рендерить вью темплиты ?

Comment: Да + ВьюХелперы + ВьюХелперы во ВьюХелперах :)

Comment: В Zend\Mvc\View\ConsoleViewManager есть getMvcRenderingStrategy. Если в нём 82-ю сторку поменять на **$this->mvcRenderingStrategy = new \Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy($this->getView())** всё начинает работать! Осталось выяснить, как это сделать без изменений в ядре :(

Comment: Как то нужно из приложения сервис DefaultRenderingStrategy  подеменить с \Zend\Mvc\View\Console\DefaultRenderingStrategy на \Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy

Comment: Возможно эта ссылка поможет. Можно добавить свой ивент и подменить стратегию. https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#creating-and-registering-alternate-rendering-and-response-strategies

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но таким образом можно поменять RendererStrategy, а нужно (как я предполагаю) MvcRenderingStrategy.

Comment: @newage , кажется, мы совместно докопались! Как тут принято благодарить за помощь?

Answer (score 1):

Из сервис локатора можно вызвать рендерер, все зивисимости для рендера будут инициализированны.

```
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');

$view = new ViewModel();
$renderer->render($view);
```

Comment: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer

Comment: Необходимо разбираться с настройками. Не могу сказать почему не видно стандартных объектов в сервис локаторе.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, как это комментировать... видимо я на столько же туп как и упрям, но... я всего лишь добавляю в

**Module.php**

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){
        ...
        if ($e->getRequest() instanceof \Zend\Console\Request) {            
            $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewManager')->getView();
        }
        ...
    }
```

И спокойно работаю с View и ViewHelper'ами по console, также как и по http... Почему? Не знаю. Но пока работает!